# seemingly simple Firestore query is very slow

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Appears Firestore is very slow recently.

A seemingly simple query like below takes 5+ seconds and there is only one document in "request" collection

```
firestore.collection('Users/blah/Request').get()
```

What can i do to make it run faster? Does it matter that Users collection's documents contain multiple collections? Just seems unreasonable to take 5 seconds for a single document.

An insert into the same "Request" collection takes a fraction of a second. The document looks like this

```
{ requester: '/Users/req', user: '/Users/blah', type:'some' }
```

both requester/user props are document references, could that affect retrieval times?

Comment: It almost certainly a factor of the quality of the network between the client and server.

Comment: crazy, THE doug stevenson is answering. Thank you. So i should try it from some other location? Have you heard of anything interfering with firestore connections? May be something on my machine?

Comment: You'll see much better performance in Cloud Functions or any Google Cloud service, as they are essentially "adjacent" to each other in network.  Mobile clients will vary greatly.